# PhD thesis format can be used for producing handout and slides?

Tags: thesis, beamerarticle

I am experimenting with the 'thesis' package by Nicola Talbot.
My first impressions are very pleasant, but I do have some questions,
because I want to use it for producing lecture slides, handout for printing
and browsable handout for mobile devices, from the same source.
Presently I do have some macros which allow to produce outputs for
`beamer`, `memoir` and `AcroTeX` slides

1. I wanted to magnify the size of text in screen mode. Is there an easy way
   to do so? (I attempted to change both points size and geometry, but in both cases
   the format collapses)
2. As I wanted to produce some beamer-like output, too, I added package beamerarticle.
   Is there any way to use it with the package?
   (if I add the package, then my pdflatex hangs)
3. I have a number of figures with small size, so I prefer 2-column format.
   It is possible? (I receive no formal error, but do not see any effect for \twocolumn)

Comment: May you highlight us with the package you're referring to? Nicola Talbot has published those packages on CTAN http://www.ctan.org/author/talbot?

Comment: @Pouya Here I did find that: http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/

Comment: @user11708, I just edited the question, I think you wanted to notify someone else `;)`

Answer (score 1):

(Another placeholder while the question is clarified. Will be removed or substantially edited later.)

---

I'm also not sure about what you mean by Nicola's package, but the following MWE makes a two-column article and a parallel beamer presentation.

196756-article.tex:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\input{196756-main}
```

196756-presentation.tex:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}

\input{196756-main}
```

196756-main.tex:

```
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\mode<presentation>{
% Remove figure and table numbers from presentation. First, beamer doesn't number
% them anyway. Second, even if it did, we might not show every table and figure
% in the presentation, and don't want to confuse Figure 1.3 in the presentation with
% Figure 1.7 in the article.
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\insertcaption}% will not show up in article, only in presentation
\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}{}%
}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\date{\today}

\AtBeginSection[]{
\begin{frame}<beamer>
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame} % shows up in both presentation and article
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}<article>  % will not show up in presentation, only in article
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{One}
\lipsum[1-3] % will not show up in presentation, only in article
\begin{frame}<beamer> % will not show up in article, only in presentation
\lipsum[1]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame} % shows up in both presentation and article
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Example Image A \label{fig:a}}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\section{Two}
\lipsum[4-6] % will not show up in presentation, only in article
\begin{frame} % shows up in both presentation and article
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Example Image B \label{fig:b}}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not exactly what I mean. Yes, using the beamerarticle package you can convert a beamer format file to an article or book. I want to use also the macros in the package (http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/)

Comment: You'll need to make a more descriptive MWE. I don't know which specific macros or packages you're talking about.